# Is this possible, GNOME (lib)Clutter with OpenGL ES & Vulkane?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, cross-platform, clutter

I'm planning to run an app based on [(GNOME) libclutter](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Clutter) on Android 9 (Pie). I'm quite new to these graphics related stuff, been wondering on these things, so seeking for guidance/direction whatever data that could help me to understand this thing better.

As per the documentation of [Android Graphics](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/), Android is using OpenGL ES & Vulkane at low level to render objects. And as per [GNOME Clutter documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/clutterbackends.html), it could be only compiled with mentioned back-end only! (Please check embedded link to for platforms details.)

I don't see OpenGL ES or Vulkane support, So am I missing something on understanding part or it can't be done?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clutter maintainer, here]

Yes, Clutter supports OpenGL ES—it uses [Cogl](https://developer.gnome.org/cogl/1.22/), a library that abstracts GL and GLES concepts.

No, Clutter does **not** support Vulkan at the moment.

No, Clutter and Cogl do not support Android; there was [an experimental port](https://github.com/clutter-project/clutter-android) but it has been abandoned in 2012.

Additionally, Clutter is in deep maintenance mode: no new development releases, no new features, and only minimal/security/crasher bug fixes are allowed.

I would not recommend using Clutter in a newly written project.

Comment: Cool! thanks @ebassi for this info. So now my question would be, as I have written in my answer below, I'm going (trying) to integrate latest v1.26 release into Android 9, Should I go for that? As a maintainer what would be your suggestion.

Comment: Also, I guess you mean "no new development releases" in 4th para of your answer, correct?

Comment: @Novice I would not recommend trying to get Clutter working on Android; there's really no point in doing so, and any further change would need to live in your own downstream code. And, yes: that "now" was a typo that I just fixed.

Comment: Thanks @ebassi! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

OKay...after spending few more hours, I was able to figure out an answer! (Yayy..!!!)

As per [Clutter Project](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Clutter) website: (somehow I had missed this info previously! :p)

> Clutter uses OpenGL for rendering (and optionally OpenGL ES for use on mobile and embedded platforms), but wraps an easy to use, efficient, flexible API around GL's complexity.

So, as per my requirement, I should be able to integrate and cross-compile Clutter lib source and compile it.

PS: I will try to integrate & build the **libclutter** on **android 9**. Will update this answer latter with additional set of information.

==========================================================================
**Update**:
As pointed out by @ebassi in another answer, I have dropped the idea of integration and looking forward to directly using [Android Graphics](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/) stack for the implementation.

Thanks @ebassi...!